# ActiveRecord::Relation's substitute_values was removed in Rails 5.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently upgraded Rails to 5.2.0 and just noticed that `substitute_values` was removed from ActiveRecord::Relation

The thing is, I can't find any documentation about it, nor where it went or why it was removed. I don't think there was a deprecation warning, at least I couldn't find it. I did a search in the Rails Github and in SO, but couldn't find anything related with it

Does anyone know why it was removed or where can I read about it? I could just use the source code from 5.1.7, but I'd like to know where it was moved (if it was) so I can use it, or if it was removed for some specific reason

Comment: It appears that [this merge](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/bbae710a405ce92074c1666dcf859196c29e2ed2#diff-18a561656864ea240daf46bdb1f50faace49f9ef74b90bcf667d9bbb17fce084) removed the public exposure of this method and moved the private implementation to `Persistence`. It looks like it has since returned to `Relation` (in [This merge](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8e123847e8ba0a59aafa708950a4887a669311b4#diff-18a561656864ea240daf46bdb1f50faace49f9ef74b90bcf667d9bbb17fce084)) however it remains an internal and privatized method.

Comment: Given that this method has very limited usage and has always been a :no doc: method, the fact that it was not deprecated, or officially announced as "removed" is not surprising because it appears to have always been treated as part of the internal API which is consistently evolving.